# Question on proving Quadratic Reciprocity with Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I'm trying to understand the proof of Quadratic Reciprocity on Wikipedia (this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_algebraic_number_theory, then the section "proof using Gauss sums" and then "general case").  I believe it's the proof in Ireland and Rossen.

Let $p$ and $q$ be primes, let $\zeta _p=e^{2\pi i/p}$ and let $g_p$ be the quadratic Gauss sum:
\[ g_p=\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}\left (\begin {array}{l}k\\ p\end {array}\right )\zeta _p^k.\]

In the article $g_p^{q-1}$ is worked out in two different ways.  First it is shown that

\[ g_p^{q-1}\equiv \left (\begin {array}{l}p^*\\ q\end {array}\right )\text { mod }q\]

where

\[ p^*=\left (\begin {array}{l}\overline -1\\ p\end {array}\right )p.\]

This is just a usual congruence in integers.  It is then shown that we also have

\[ g_p^q\equiv \sum _{k=1}^{p-1}\left (\begin {array}{l}k\\ p\end {array}\right )^q\zeta ^{qk}\text { mod }q\]

which is a congruence in the ring $\mathbb Z[\zeta _p]$, meaning literally
\[ g_p^q-\left (\begin {array}{l}\overline q\\ p\end {array}\right )g_p=g_p^q-\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}\left (\begin {array}{l}k\\ p\end {array}\right )^q\zeta ^{qk}=qZ\]
for some

\[ Z=\sum _{r=0}^{p-1}A_r\zeta ^r\in \mathbb Z[\zeta _p].\]

Consequently

\[ g_p^{q-1}-\left (\begin {array}{l}\overline q\\ p\end {array}\right )=qg_p^{-1}Z\]

and we can compare the two expressions for $g_p^{q-1}$ to deduce

\[ \left (\begin {array}{l}\overline q\\ p\end {array}\right )\equiv \left (\begin {array}{l}p^*\\ q\end {array}\right )\text { mod }q.\]

Where exactly thist last congruence is taken isn't clear to me though - whether it's a congruence in integers or in $\mathbb Z[\zeta _p]$.  If it's in $\mathbb Z[\zeta _p]$, then we need to know that $1\not \equiv -1\text { mod }q$ which isn't obvious.  But if I look at one of the oldest proofs, due to Cauchy, where no notion of $\mathbb Z[\zeta _p]$ was available, then it seems to say it's actually a congruence in integers?  But I can't read French (or maths xD) so maybe I'm just not understanding what's going on.  Here's the text:

https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_hzIVAAAAQAAJ/page/n411/mode/2up

where towards the bottom of page 393 I think he shows that the difference I'm looking for really is an integer.

Is $g_p^{-1}Z\in \mathbb Z$?  And if not how does the above proof work, if we're being precise about congruences?

It may be something simple I'm missing and that's why it's not written out explicitly (cause it's not written in the Rossen and Ireland text either).

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: The notation for the Legendre symbol is $(\frac{k}p)$

Comment: See the comments to the answer by Jared Weinstein on the MO page https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1420/whats-the-best-proof-of-quadratic-reciprocity. The issue you raise about subtleties over where a congruence takes place is discussed there. This is why I stopped using the Gauss sum proof when teaching elementary number theory courses and started using a proof by V. A. Lebesgue that is described in my own answer on that page (username KConrad there). If you don’t want to refer to “rings and fields” in the proof then you should not use the Gauss sum proof.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look now.  

hmm, it's disconcerning that i shouldn't use that. my hope was that it was possible to keep things explicit without it getting messy (since gauss/cauchy would have not been able to refer to rings and fields, but i have no idea how difficult/easy this part of the proof was). i guess not then

Comment: @KCd There is no issue and the OP is wrong in saying that "congruence should obviously be in integers". From $g_p=\pm \sqrt{\pm p}$ it is obvious what is integer and what is not.

Comment: aah right, so the final congruence is also not an integer congruence.  i see.  i'll edit that.  

something is still to be said though, as the original proofs (gauss, or cauchy's one, which i linked) have to deal with this point.  can you clarify that?

Comment: I do not know if Gauss worked with congruences or a more explicit method when using Gauss sums. Fields and rings were defined only in the early 20th century as *abstract* concepts.  Special cases had been used long before then. You do not need to know about abstract rings and fields to use particular examples like $\mathbf Z[\zeta_p]/(q)$.

Comment: when i write things explicitly, i think i get that the final task is to show that $2p/q\not \in \mathbb Z[\zeta _p]$ (this is slightly different to what you have in that other thread, but i don't know if maybe you were just "sketching" or if i did something wrong). this would follow from the irreduciblity of $1+x+...+x^{p-1}$ over $\mathbb Q$ (right?) which is what Gauss showed.  have i understood correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Here "$\bmod q$" means in the ring $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]/(q)$.

$\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]/(q)$ is a commutative ring of characteristic $q$ (prime) so that for any of its elements we have $(a+b)^q =a^q+b^q$. Also for any integer $n^q=n$. Whence in that ring $$(\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}(\frac{k}p)\zeta^k)^q=\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}(\frac{k}p)^q\zeta^{qk}=\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}(\frac{k}p)\zeta^{qk}$$

---

You don't care that $g_p^q-g_p= g_p m$ for some integer $m$ (when $p,q$ are odd), and it is obvious from $g_p = \pm \sqrt{\pm p}$. You can also see it from some Galois theory, namely any automorphism $\sigma $ of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is such that $\sigma(g_p)=\pm g_p$ (this follows from $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^l$ for some $\gcd(l,q)=1$). Then $q$ must divide this integer $m$ because $g_p\ne 0\bmod q$ (this follows from $g_p^2=\pm p$).

Comment: thanks for the answer:)

maybe i didn't make it clear in my original post: so i understand it's true if i think about $\mathbb Z[\zeta ]$ but i want to convince myself of its truth *without* having to refer to rings and fields.

Comment: No, there is no alternative, this is what it means.

Comment: let's say we didn't know the $(a+b)^q=a^q+b^q$ for rings of characteristic $p$, how would you do it then?  Gauss and Cauchy didn't have these concepts (right?) so they would have had to write out that fact explicitly.  i'm asking: how is that done?

Comment: Here $\bmod q$ means that $g_p^q-g_p = q c$ for some $c\in \Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$. From the binomial expansion it is evident  that for $a,b\in \Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$,  $(a+b)^q=a^q+b^q+qd$ for some $d\in \Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$. Why do you care of the prehistory of maths? I mean the Gauss sum proof of quadratic reciprocity is based on quotient rings of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$, you can't avoid those.

Comment: but $d\in \mathbb Z$, that's the crucial bit.  see the link in the comment to cauchy's argument.  

like i said in the post, i'm aware that what's actually going on is ideals of $\mathbb Z[\zeta ]$.  "i want to be able to go through the proof with people maybe not knowing algebraic number theory.

Comment: Why do you think $d$ is in $\Bbb{Z}$, and why would you need it, and avoiding algebraic number theory in the gauss sum proof of quadratic reciprocity doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry, i meant $gd\in \mathbb Z$.  this is what i don't get.

i dont think it's enough just to know $d\in \mathbb Z[\zeta ]$.  (remember the conclusion we want is that $(a+b)^qg\equiv a^qg+b^qg$ as the usual congruence)

Comment: It is not the case. $g_p =\pm \sqrt{\pm p}$. The conclusion we want is what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: i'll change my question to make it clear why what you wrote (is correct but) not enough

Comment: What we want is knowing the sign in $(\frac{p}q)=p^{(q-1)/2}= \pm 1\bmod q$, for this we look a the Gauss sum $g_p = \pm \sqrt{\pm p}=\sum _{k=1}^{p-1}(\frac{k}p)\zeta^k$, we find that $g_p^q = \pm  g_p\bmod q$ where the sign is $=(\frac{q}p)$, whence $(\pm p)^{(q-1)/2} = (\frac{q}p)\bmod q$. It remains to investigate the latter sign.

Comment: i agree with that, i just dont think it answers my question.  anyway, i've edited my question now.  hopefully it's clearer what i'm confused about :)

Comment: You don't care that $g_p^q-g_p= g_p m$ for some integer $m$, and it is obvious from $g_p = \pm \sqrt{\pm p}$. You can also see it from some Galois theory, namely any automorphism $\sigma $ of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is such that $\sigma(g_p)=\pm g_p$ (this follows from $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^l$ for some $\gcd(l,q)=1$). Then $q$ must divide this integer $m$ because $g_p\ne 0\bmod q$.

Comment: i dont understand your last comment.  i agree we dont care that $g^q-g=gm$.  its not what my question says. my question has has a clear problem: why is $gZ$ an integer?

Comment: I explained everything. It is not an integer. Stop confusing everything and use $g_p=\pm \sqrt{\pm p}$.

Comment: i'm sorry if i'm missing something simple.  but your comments don't make sense to me - they seem to not understand what i'm missing, and they even seem to me as though you've overlooking something (but maybe i'm wrong).  i've written out more details in my question now, maybe that changes something?

Comment: I explained everything. You don't need to look at $Z$, you don't care of it. My $m$ is an integer and a multiple of $q$. There is **nothing else to say**.

Comment: The sketch proof of quadratic reciprocity is in my comment above: "What we want is knowing the sign in" as you see I didn't look at Z.